# Is there any way to tell Mathematica NOT to simplify an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, input

I have this expression:

```
Lx = (ℏ/I)*(-Sqrt[15/(8*π)])*(-Sin[ϕ]*(Cos[2*θ]*E^(I*ϕ)) -
  Cos[ϕ]*Cot[θ]*(I*Cos[θ]*Sin[θ]*E^(I*ϕ)))
```

and I don't want *Mathematica* to do anything to simplify it. I want to see it as input in the exact way I've written it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following maybe.

```
HoldForm[(\[HBar]/
I)*(-Sqrt[
 15/(8*\[Pi])])*(-Sin[\[Phi]]*(Cos[2*\[Theta]]*E^(I*\[Phi])) - 
Cos[\[Phi]]*
 Cot[\[Theta]]*(I*Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]*E^(I*\[Phi])))]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was doubtful that such a command even existed, but that worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @whatwhatwhat also you can use simply `Hold[...]` for similar results.  Make sure to mark as accept if you like the answer.